# Does the electric field of a charge bend inside a gravitational field?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, photons

I was invited to review an [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358813301_Bending_of_Electric_Field_Lines_and_Photon_Trajectories_in_a_Static_Gravitational_Field) by one of the IOP journals (Journal of Physics Communications) a few months ago in which the author claimed that the EM fields, similar to photons, *bend* in a gravitational field. The calculations were slightly hard and I had not enough time to follow the calculations, and thus I had to decline to review the article. However, the article inspired me to consider that every single electric (or magnetic) field may have a photon-like behavior and it bends inside a gravitational field. Is this a rational deduction?

Comment: The effect of gravity on classical EM fields can and should be understood without ever thinking about photons. You simply solve [Maxwell’s equations in curved spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime). For example, there is an exact solution for a point charge at rest outside a Schwarzschild black hole, and the field lines are bent. They do *not* follow photon trajectories, nor is there any reason to think that they should.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the field would be bent. There are a couple ways to get at it. Both a similar to calculating what happens to light in a gravitational field.

First consider a spherical mass and the Schwarzschild metric. A point charge sits some distance away. This is a static case, so we can ignore time dilation near the mass.

The electric field is defined by the force a test charge would feel at a point. The force depends on the distance between the charge and test charge. Distance near the mass is distorted. It is farther to the surface of the mass than it would be in flat space. You would measure the distance along a geodesic.

The magnitude of the field is constant on a sphere defined by a constant distance from the charge. The field would be perpendicular to this sphere. This sphere has a different shape than a sphere in flat space. Vectors perpendicular to its surface point in different directions than vectors perpendicular to a flat space sphere. So the field is bent.

---

Another way is to consider that gravity is equivalent to acceleration. Suppose you have an charge that is also a light source. Both field lines and light rays follow a path radially outward.

Now accelerate the charge. At each instant, a shell of light is emitted. It travels outward at c from the point where the charge was. You, sitting on the charge, see rays bent as they are left behind.

The field lines are bent the same way. Imaging test charges in a shell around some point of the trajectory. Some time after the charge passes, light that left the center arrives at the shell. At the same time, the test charges feel an electric force from when the charge was at the center. The force and electric field are in the same direction as the light rays.

Comment: I am still not convinced why the electric field lines behave as photon trajectories.

Comment: I updated the answer with more explanation.